# mediaplayer.start() and mediaplayer.pause() crashing the app

Tags: android

// Necessary libraries are imported.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void playAudio(View view) {
        mPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hahah);
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pauseAudio(View view) {
        mPlayer.pause();
    }

}
```

This is my MainActivity. The app crashes as soon as I press play or pause button. This app works when I remove both the buttons and allow it to start playing automatically in onCreate method.

Comment: Open the logcat viewer. A stacktrace should be given when the app crashes. There's also no code where the mPlayer is being instantiated.

Comment: post crash logcat here

Comment: where you init.. `mPlayer` object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer =new MediaPlayer();
```

in onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize `class` before using it. `Object` is not created for the `mplayer`.

Initialize it in the `onCreate()` method

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer =new MediaPlayer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, whenever you define a variable but don't assign value to it, it will crash the app. Here you are creating a `MediaPlayer` but not assigning it. You should add this code in your `onCreate()` method:

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

This will create a new instance of the `MediaPlayer` object and you can reuse the functions of that class.